# Identify wire insulation for temperature rating

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image]

I need some help identifying wire that feeds a sub-panel. What is known:

- 2 AWG
- Aluminum
- Softer, more flexible insulation

My guess is it's silicone or rubber, definitely not PVC. See the attached photo. The 4 aluminum wires are at the top connected to the 60A breakers. The pair below it connected to the 50A breakers feel like more common PVC insulation.

I'm trying to figure out the insulation rating so I know whether it's safe to increase the breaker to 90A (75C) or 80A (60C). I can't make out any useful markings on the insulation. The markings I've found don't return anything useful online.

Update: Here are the markings on the wire. It's crummy dot matrix printing that's difficult to read. All the areas with "Type" are partly or completely rubbed off. See the attached photo for two places I managed to get a few dots of it. First two letters look like an XH, then maybe K... ?

I first read part of the marking as "AA3176", but there are search hits for "AA8176" not 3176.

(UL) AWG 2 COMPACT AL ALUMAFLEX (TM)
AA8176 TYPE XH..?  M HFS
600 VOLTS 6/06/2006 N. GEMBE
The wire with the red stripe also has T. THOMAS
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try this "more comprehensive than most" listing, or tell us / show us (pictures are good) what markings you have found. The insulation type code is part of the text that repeats every 2-3 feet. Silicone would be unusual (it's relatively fragile.) https://www.multicable.com/resources/reference-data/wire-abbreviations-and-descriptions/

Comment: Are those wires from a cable? The markings would then be on the cable sheath.

Comment: Yes, can you trace those wires to where they exit the box, and get us photos of that exit point please?

Comment: The top black wire has markings, it is 2 AWG compact stranded.  The only 60C wire known is TW, so it is almost certainly 75C or 90C thermal wire, allowing 90A.

Comment: The wires exit the bottom-right of the box (see added a photo). They are individual wires, not in a sheathed bundle. I'll open it up to get as many markings as I can off it

Comment: Even if 90c you Can not use that table for the breaker size as the panel is only 75c. What year was the home built there are some states that will only allow older aluminum to use the 60C table.

Comment: Added all the markings I could make out.  @EdBeal home was built in 2007

Comment: With a newer home the wiring would be allowed to use the 75c for the ampacity and the 90c for derating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, XHH or XHHW, either of which are 90 °C wire, unless wet (only correctly applicable to XHHW) where it's 75 °C (or XHHW-2 is 90 °C wet or dry.)

Cross linked polyethylene.

Enjoy your 90 Amps.

Comment: woot! thanks @Ecnerwal